# How to match unicorn with rails 4.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

The ruby program worked well before at version 2.1.11, but new bundler requires ruby version >= 2.3. So I upgrade ruby version to 2.4.5, bundler 1.17.3, rails version to 4.2.11, nokogiri to 1.7.2, therubyracer to 0.12.3, unicorn version to 5.0.1, Gemfile as follows:

> gem 'rails', '4.2.11' gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13' gem 'sass-rails',
>   '4.0.1' gem 'uglifier', '2.3.1' gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1' gem
>   'therubyracer', '0.12.3', platforms: :ruby gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
>   gem 'turbolinks', '1.3.1' gem 'jbuilder', '1.5.2'
>
> group :doc do   gem 'sdoc', require: false end gem 'unicorn', '5.0.1'
>   gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3' gem 'haml-rails' gem 'rbhive', '0.5.1' gem
>   'devise', '3.2.2' gem 'net-ldap', '0.5.1' gem
>   'devise_ldap_authenticatable' gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.5' gem
>   'delayed_job_active_record', '4.1.0' gem 'delayed_job', '4.1.0' gem
>   'jquery-turbolinks', '2.0.2' gem 'jquery-ace-rails', '1.0.1' gem
>   'filterrific', '3.0.0' gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', '1.3.0.1'
>
> gem 'rake', '10.4.2' gem 'mysql2', '0.3.16' gem 'whenever', '0.9.2'
>   gem 'activerecord-import', '0.10.0' gem 'delayed_job_web', '1.4' gem
>   'hbase-stargate', '1.6.1' gem 'daemons', '1.1.9'

But there error occurs:

```
/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from /root/keeper/deploy/presto_ui/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /root/keeper/deploy/presto_ui/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
        from /root/keeper/deploy/presto_ui/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from config.ru:3:in `require'
        from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from config.ru:1:in `new'
        from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn.rb:46:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn.rb:46:in `block in builder'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:752:in `build_app!'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:129:in `start'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

I wonder if unicorn doesn't match to rails or other reason?  What should I do to fix it??

Answer (score 1):

Try to downgrade version of unicorn, step by step: https://rubygems.org/gems/unicorn/versions (check all versions here)

Check by RoR 4.2.11 release date what was the version of unicorn at that time.

Comment: I am running rails 4.2.10 with unicorn 5.1.0 so actually maybe upgrade of unicorn might help

Comment: it doesn't matter what version. try to compare versions by release date.